# How is $40$ related to $60$?

Tags: ratio

My problem with math is how I talk about it, the words of math.  I know math is a language but I don’t translate it very well.

For example, if you have $40$ units and I have $60$ units, from my perspective, you have a third fewer than I do.   From your perspective I have half as many again.  It’s all relative.  Do I have a third more or a half more?  Do you have a third less or a half less?  Either way it’s still $20$ units in question.  Where am I mistranslating the problem?

Comment: If $a$ has 40% fewer dollars than $b$, how much does $a$ have if $b$ has 100 dollars?

Answer (score 1):

Percentages change depending on the base. Your second sentence it exactly correct and you should have stopped there.  You have half more. I have a third less.  The problem comes because you think these are contradictory.  They are not.  From a mathematical perspective, (if we scale it) I have $1$ and you have $1+x/100$, so you have $x\%$ more than me.  Claiming I have $x\%$ less than you is claiming $(1+x/100)(1-x/100)=1$, which is false. $(1+x/100)(1-x/100)=1-x^2/10,000$.  If $x$ is small, you can ignore the last term and your intuition works.